# How do you override bootstrap.min.css? Django

Tags: css, django

On my page I have a toolbar which is supposed to be centered in the middle. I have a seperate css sheet which centres it, however it keeps being overriden by the min.css file.

In my body content.css I have:

```
.btn-toolbar .btn, .btn-toolbar .btn-group, .btn-toolbar .input-group {
  float:none !important;
}
```

But when I inspect the page via the console it it always shows this in the min.css:

```
.btn-toolbar .btn, .btn-toolbar .btn-group, .btn-toolbar .input-group {
  float:left;
}
```

How do I override it?

Answer (score 2):

On `<head>` reorder your CSS files:

```
<!--CSS-->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="contents.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't advice you change `bootstrap.min.css` . create new class and use it.
for example

```
      .my-toolbar {
           float:none !important;
      }
```

Comment: i already have a class called "btn-group" and a button class called "btn btn-default". Where do I make this new class?

Comment: In your custom css files. And your custom classes name should not same with bootstrap classes
Also you must add your css files after `bootstrap.min.css`